# PickerView: Type 'ViewController' does not conform to protocol 'UIPickerViewDataSource'

Tags: swift3, xcode8

I am using code from a sample project. It does work in the sample project, but not in my project.

**SettingsViewController.swift:**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {
    let days:[String] = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return days.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return days[row]
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

I am using Xcode 8.2.1, Swift 2.3

Comment: The code shown in your question seems fine. A couple of minor things, you do not need to specify the type on the `days` array and semicolons are not required after declarations. Beyond that, I cannot reproduce the compile time error on Xcode 8.2.1.

Comment: Thx for the response. Seems I am using Swift 2.3 (Use Legacy Swift Language Version = Yes) in the other project.

Comment: This SO question is similar, albeit the opposite of what your need. http://stackoverflow.com/q/39933644/4748172 (Swift 2.3 to Swift 3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method signature for `numberOfComponents(in:)` changed from iOS 9.3 to iOS 10. Since you are targeting a legacy version of Swift, replace your current implementation of `numberOfComponents(in:)` with the appropriate version below.

**Swift 2.3**

```
func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
```

**Swift 3**

```
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
```

---

The API changes can be seen here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/iOS10APIDiffs/Swift/UIKit.html

*Modified* **UIPickerViewDataSource**

Declaration

From

```
protocol UIPickerViewDataSource : NSObjectProtocol {
    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int
}
```

To

```
protocol UIPickerViewDataSource : NSObjectProtocol {
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int
}
```