# iOS - Error Type 'ViewController' does not conform to protocol 'UIPickerViewDataSource'

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

I've done a lot of searching but I couldn't find the solution to my issue.
This is my first year of Swift, so please nothing "too advanced".

Here's my code:

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {
    // Properties
    @IBOutlet weak var name_tf: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var artist_tf: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var sort_pkr: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var sort_lbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var sorted_lbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var next_lbl: UILabel!

    let pickerData = ["Song name","Artist"]

    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return pickerData.count
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return pickerData[row]
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        sort_lbl.text = pickerData[row]
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let pickerView = UIPickerView()
        pickerView.delegate = self
        pickerView.dataSource = self
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
```

I have a feeling I'm not placing my functions in the correct spot.

Comment: Are you using Swift 3? If so, the methods got renamed. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39933644/xcode-8-swift-3-simple-uipicker-code-not-working

Comment: Easy and quick do-it-yourself solution: Press ⇧⌘0 (zero), type `UIPickerViewDataSource` (later `UIPickerViewDelegate` for the other methods), select `Swift`, press return and look up the signatures.

Comment: Thank you, vikingosegundo, that post solved my problem. I didn't know I was updated from swift 2.3 to 3 (I'm using school Macs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For ***Swift 3***, use these functions:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

   }
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

   }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.