# 2 PickerViews on same ViewController - titleForRow fund "will not be executed"

Tags: ios, swift3, tags, uipickerview

I've tagged the PickerViews 1 and 2 but I'm getting a "will not be executed" message on the func titleForRow, how do I solve this?

```
@IBOutlet weak var shoeDetailPic: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var shoeDetailName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var shoeDetailPrice: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var shoeColourPickerView: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet weak var shoeSizePickerView: UIPickerView!

var pickerColour = [""]
var pickerSize = [""]

var getName = String()
var getPrice = String()
var getImage = UIImage()


override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()


shoeDetailPic.image = getImage
shoeDetailName.text = getName
shoeDetailPrice.text = getPrice

pickerColour = ["Gold", "Black", "Red"]
pickerSize = ["35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42"]

}




override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1

}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component:   Int) -> Int {
    if (pickerView.tag == 1){
        return pickerColour.count
    }else{
        return pickerSize.count
    }
```

Message here - will not be executed. Is it something to do with the IBOutlet names?

```
  func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent    component: Int) -> String?{
        if (pickerView.tag == 1){
            return "\(pickerColour[row])"
        }else{
            return "\(pickerSize[row])"
        }

}
}
}
```

Comment: Add a screen shot here with warning.

Comment: Please try 
 if (pickerView.tag == 1){
            return pickerColour[row]
        }else{
            return pickerSize[row]
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is you have put `titleForRow` delegate method inside the `numberOfRowsInComponent`, it should be outside of that method as instance method of class.

```
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    if (pickerView == shoeColourPickerView){
        return pickerColour.count
    }else{
        return pickerSize.count
    }
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    if (pickerView == shoeColourPickerView){
        return pickerColour[row]
    }else{
        return pickerSize[row]
    }

}
```

**Note:** You have already created outlet for both `pickerView` then instead of comparing `tag` in delegate method it is batter if you compare with your outlet.

Comment: Ahh I see! That has got rid of that problem but I now have this error

Comment: 2017-03-29 13:46:47.089 projectA[34754:2031417] -[projectA.shoeDetailViewController numberOfComponentsInPickerView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f939fd235a0
2017-03-29 13:46:48.685 projectA[34754:2031417] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[projectA.shoeDetailViewController numberOfComponentsInPickerView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f939fd235a0'

Comment: Yes I am using Swift 3

Comment: @Zed Check this answer of my in Swift 3 delegate method's signature is changed http://stackoverflow.com/a/39933750/6433023 change your method like this will solve your problem

Comment: @Zed I have also edited answer with new methods replace your one with my edited methods

Comment: @Zed Edit your question with new code, add whole controller code

Comment: I was missing a data source connection...sorry I'm really new to this! Thanks for all your help, its all working now!

Comment: @Zed Welcome mate :)