# UIPickerView on Swift 3

Tags: swift

I have error with using `UIPickerView`

```
SelectViewController.swift:35:10: Method 'pickerView(pickerView:numberOfRowsInComponent:)' has different argument names from those required by protocol 'UIPickerViewDataSource' ('pickerView(_:numberOfRowsInComponent:)')
```

I set `UIPickerView` on Storyboard and attached this to the songPicker variable.

and then I think I integrated the functions necessary though, it showed error like this.

I found out that structure of picker view is changed on the version of swift.

However can't find the correct answer yet.

My swift is 3.1

Does anyone help me?

```
class SelectViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var songPicker: UIPickerView!

    let songNames = ["test","test2"]

    override func viewDidLoad(){
            songPicker.delegate = self
          songPicker.dataSource = self

    }
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }


    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return songNames.count
    }
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int) -> String? {
        return songNames[row]
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {

    }
}
```

Comment: Remove this func .. 
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this method, see the use of `_` before pickerview. That is the only problem

```
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

    }
```

Comment: Thanks it works! I need to learn Swift more. BTW,my pickerviews show only '?' in the field instead of "test1" "test2" this might be another problem though....

Comment: I think there may be some other problem. Need your full code to check, otherwise, the code that you provided should show test1 and test2

Answer (score 2):

try this code

```
class ElibraryViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var txtTitle: UITextField!
 @IBOutlet weak var Picker: UIPickerView!
let songNames = ["test","test2"]

override func viewDidLoad()
    {

        super.viewDidLoad()


            }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String?
    {


            return songNames[row]
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)
    {



        let obj = songNames[row]
        txtTitle.text = obj



    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {

        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int
    {



        return songNames.count



    }
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {

    }
}
```

Comment: there is no meaning in repeating answers?, you already seen there is same answer available, then why to put the same thing again?. Make the stackoverflow a better place.

Answer (score 1):

`UIPickerViewDataSource` is changes in swift 3 and above.

**Updated syntax:-**

```
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return arrayData.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return arrayData[row]
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

}
```

Have a look at [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uipickerview) ([SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43497604/988169) reference).

Comment: there is no meaning in repeating answers?, you already seen there is same answer available, then why to put the same thing again?. Make the stackoverflow a better place.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use IQDropDownTextField - [Click Here](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQDropDownTextField)