# Swift picker input value set to specified url

Tags: swift, uipickerview, xcode9.2

I am pretty new to working with Swift. I am making an iPhone app using Swift that has a view with a label "Choose State" and a picker view that contains all 50 states in USA.

I am trying to assign each item in the picker view to a specified url that matches that state's DMV website address. (Example: user selects Kansas, when they hit 'done/submit' they are segued to another view controller that has a Webkit View that loads "https://www.dmv.org/ks-kansas/".

I have been searching and have not found anything online that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a dictionary like this

```
 var dic = [String:String]()
```

key represents the state , and value the url , title of the picker is the keys of the dictionary and when you click get the url value

and here how to implement the picker:  [PickerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39933644/xcode-8-swift-3-simple-uipicker-code-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

- Get the US states as JSON from https://gist.github.com/mshafrir/2646763, the `states_titlecase.json` version.
- Add a new key value pair in each dictionary for the last path component of the URL for example

  ```
  {
     "name": "Kansas",
     "abbreviation": "KS",
     "urlPath" : "ks-kansas/"
  }
  ```
- Decode the JSON with `JSONDecoder` of Swift 4 into an array of struct.
- Use the array as data source for the picker view.
- Show `name` or `abbreviation` to the user.
- When the user picks a value compose the URL with

  ```
  let url = URL(string: "https://www.dmv.org")!.appendingPathComponent(state.urlPath)
  ```

Answer (score 0):

**1.** First of all, you need to create a `dataSource` that you can use in `UIPickerView`. It must contain a `title` and `link` for all the `rows` that you want to show in the `UIPickerView`, i.e.

```
let data = [
    [
        "title": "Kansas",
        "link": "https://www.dmv.org/ks-kansas/"
    ],

    [
        "title": "Title-1",
        "link": "Link-1"
    ],

    [
        "title": "Title-2",
        "link": "Link-2"
    ],

    [
        "title": "Title-3",
        "link": "Link-3"
    ]
]
```

**2.** Next, you need to implement `UIPickerViewDataSource` and `UIPickerViewDelegate` methods in your `UIViewController`, i.e.

```
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int
{
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int
{
    return data.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String?
{
    return data[row]["title"]
}
```

Don't forget to set the `delegate` and `dataSource` of `UIPickerView` in `viewDidLoad()`.

```
@IBOutlet weak var pickerView: UIPickerView!

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
}
```

**3.** Now, on `UIButton` press, you need to get the `selected row's` `link` in `UIPickerView` and send it to `AnotherViewController` that contains a `UIWebView`, i.e.

```
@IBAction func onTapDoneButton(_ sender: UIButton)
{
    let anotherController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AnotherViewController") as! AnotherViewController
    anotherController.urlString = self.data[self.pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]["link"]
    self.present(anotherController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

**4.** Here is the code for `AnotherViewController` that contains the `UIWebView`.

```
class AnotherViewController: UIViewController
{
    var urlString: String?
    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if let urlString = self.urlString, let url = URL(string: urlString)
        {
            self.webView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: url))
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if you still face any issues.